# WSH multidimensional hash/array

Tags: jscript, wsh

I try to create the following structure:

```
colItems = new Array;
colItems[0] = new Object;
colItems[0].name = "Name";
colItems[0].title = "Title";
colItems[0].path = "Path";
```

All data there is pre-defined. I wonder if there is any other way to code it in a more compact and readable way, like this:

```
colItems = new Array(
    1 => {
        name => "Name";
        title => "Title"
        ....
    },
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- To create an array literally, use [elm1, ...] (cf [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Array_literals))
- To create an object literally, use {prop:val}, ...] (cf [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Object_literals))
- To create an array of objects literally, use [{prop:val, ...}, ...]

> ```
> var a = [1, 2, 3];
> var o = {'n':'adam'};
> var ao = [{'n':'eve'},{'n':'adam'}];
> print(ao[1].n);
> adam
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Ekkehard.Horner, I extented this a bit, and below is a multi-line sample:

```
colItems = [
    {
        "name":"Name",
        "title": "Title",
        "path": [1, 2, 3],
        "fname": {
            "a":"s",
            "d":"f"
        }
    },
    {
        "name":"Name2",
        "names":"NameS",
        "title": "Title2",
        "path": [4, 5, 6],
        "fname": {
            "a":"w",
            "d":"R"
        }
    }
];
```